# sed/awk find a pattern and print everything before and after until another pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

File looks like this:

```
2014-09-18 01:00:00 some txt1 .....
...................................
...................................
2014-09-18 01:00:01 some txt2 .....
...................................
2014-09-18 01:00:02 some txt3 .....
...................................
.....my-pattern....................
...................................
2014-09-18 01:00:03 some txt4 .....
...................................
```

I need to print every line before and after my-pattern UNTIL the first occurence of a date so after it should look like this:

```
2014-09-18 01:00:02 some txt3 .....
...................................
.....my-pattern....................
...................................
```

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: This isn't quite the same as that. This is needing the entirety of a date-stamped "record" when that "record" contains a pattern. The sort of answer in that linked question can be used but need to accumulate the lines instead of printing them out and use a second state flag to trigger printing once the pattern is hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` makes it really straight forward using `RS` and `RT`:

```
awk -v RS='201[0-9]' '/my-pattern/ {print f $0} {f=RT}' file
2014-09-18 01:00:02 some txt3 .....
...................................
.....my-pattern....................
..................................
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
awk '/^2014/ {
              if (f) {for (i=1;i<=var;i++) print data[i]}
              {f=0; delete data; var=0}
             }
     {data[++var]=$0}
     /my-pattern/ {f=1}
   ' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/^2014/ {}` #when line starts by 2014, do...
- `if (f) {for (i=1;i<=var;i++) print data[i]}` if flag is set, print stored data
- `{f=0; delete data; var=0}` reset flags and data storage for next block
- `{data[++var]=$0}` store all data for every line
- `/my-pattern/ {f=1}` if line contains my-pattern, set flag on

#### Test

```
$ awk '/^2014/ {if (f) {for (i=1;i<=var;i++) print data[i]} {f=0; delete data; var=0}} {data[++var]=$0} /my-pattern/ {f=1}' a
2014-09-18 01:00:02 some txt3 .....
...................................
.....my-pattern....................
...................................
```